# return r function with numbers in expression

Tags: r, function, if-statement, return

I want ot create a functions to reutn another functions based on parameters. As you can see in the bode below, when a method='local', it return a number which is correct, but when is selected method='emep' & n=0, it should return `function(V) {(281* V ^-0.63)*det[1,1]}` but it's returning `function(V) {(281* V ^-0.63)*det[i,j]}`.
How can i fix this?

```
    f <- function(i,j, method,n, V,...){
      fen <- matrix(data=runif(50*25),nrow=50,ncol=25)
      det <- matrix(data=runif(50*25),nrow=50,ncol=25)
      ifelse(method=='local',
             return(fen[i,j]*det[i,j]),
             ifelse((method=='emep' & n == 0),
             return(function(V) {(281* V ^-0.63)*det[i,j]}),'na'))
    }


f(1,1,'local')
f(1,1,'emep',0)


function(V) {(281* V ^-0.63)*det[i,j]}
<environment: 0x609af48>
```

Many thanks!

Comment: If you evaluate the function that returned `out<-f(1,1,'emep',0); out(1)`, doesn't it work?

Comment: it's not what i'm looking for.  If i do `out<-f(1,1,'emep',0); out(1)`, it returns a number, but i need the formula F(V) instead.

Comment: Also, don't use `ifelse()` here. You want `if` and `else` for program control; `ifelse()` is for operations on vectors.

Comment: If you look at `ls(environment(f(1,1,'emep',0)))`, `i` and `j` are defined in the function's environment, so you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I will try

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is possible. R will print out the formula definition or evaluate the formula, but I don't think it will print out the formula with given arguments, but unevaluated. You could cheat and print out a character string using `paste`, if that suffices:

```
return(paste0("function(V) {(281* V ^-0.63)*det["i",",","j,"]}"),'na'))
```

Comment: At the beginning it didnt work but then added eval(parse(text=paste0("..."))) and it workked perfectly. Thanks